# ng-class does not remove a class that was there before angular was bootstrapped

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Still under 72 hours coming up to speed with angular. Having used knockout for a while, I have to say it's interesting. My question right now has to do with ng-class.

Say I have the following:

```
<div class="myClass" ng-class="{myClass: false}">
```

When angular bootstraps, it does not remove the myClass attribute that was rendered there before. I had expected it to, since that's what ko's css binding does. It seems that angular only removes the class if angular was the one who put it there.

So, is there a common workaround for this? Other than creating a custom directive?

Comment: It helps to think about Angular declaratively.  ngClass is generally used to conditionally add a class depending on whatever the specified condition.  What's your goal in having both an Angular and non-angular class declaration?

Comment: I have a form that comes back after a postback declares it as invalid. Until we can get a remote validator in there, I want to initialize a field decorator with a 'has-error' class. It works, however when the field changes to valid, and the class changes to 'has-success', the previous 'has-error' class remains, since it was rendered by the server. It's mostly a flicker thing -- I don't want the class to automatically switch on after angular bootstraps, I want it to be there from the beginning.

Comment: If I'm following, then you could then have two ngClass statements- {has-success: valid} and {has-error: !valid}.  Is that along the lines of what you're thinking?

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what I have: `ng-class="{ 'has-success': t3.f.isGoodToGo(f.fieldName), 'has-error': t3.f.needsAttention(f.fieldName) }"` -- and the server pre-renders one of these if the page is delivered after a postback.

Comment: And I'm assuming you need this element to show before Angular bootstraps?  Otherwise we could use ngCloak, for instance, to hide everything until bootstrap completes (and thus avoid flicker): http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak

Comment: Even if you use ng-cloak, there is still a flicker thing going on. We're talking about an input form field here. If I cloak, then I might as well cloak the whole form. But if I cloak the form, it will flicker on after the main page layout loads. This is not for a SPA, it is just a bit of angular added to help validate a form.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44344/discussion-between-kayakdave-and-danludwig)

Comment: ng-class also fails to remove classes that it added, but with a low 10% probability.  `ng-class="{'previous-class': false, 'any-class-except-previous-class': true}"` `ng-class="any-class-except-previous-class"` nothing works, even though the `any-class-except-previous-class` does get added... so this has nothing to do with the fact that the class is there before bootstrapping, it is some other bug.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you're only using Angular for the form and need a class to be active on elements within the form prior to Angular bootstraping it looks like a directive may be the best way to go.

The following directive will remove the specified class from the element its on once the directive is linked in by Angular (which is almost the same point when `ngClass` will kick in):

```
.directive('removeClass', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,element, attrs){
            element.removeClass(attrs.removeClass);
        }
    };
});
```

Used like so:

```
<div class="oldClass" remove-class="oldClass" ng-class="{newClass: true}">stuff</div>
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jpuj7/2/)

Comment: That's simple enough. It also seems to work with `<div class="hasClassA" remove-class="hasClassA hasClassB">stuff</div>` and `<div class="hasClassB" remove-class="hasClassA hasClassB">stuff</div>`

Comment: Yep, since [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) will take a list of space separated classes we happily don't have to do anything special to handle that